# Is the integral of $dK$ equal the work done?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

$$\frac{dK}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} (1/2 mv^2) = mv \frac{dv}{dt} = F\frac{dx}{dt}$$

$$\implies dK = F. dr$$

Also, work is defined as $W = \int F. dr$.

So does this imply integral $dK = W$?

Comment: Yes you are right. That is the Work-energy theorem that you derived.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{dK}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} (1/2 mv^2) = mv \frac{dv}{dt} $$

With $\frac{dv}{dt}=a$, and $F=ma$ then:

$$\frac{dK}{dt} = mav=ma \frac{dx}{dt}$$

$$dK=Fdx$$

So, if integrated between the right boundaries:

$$K=\int Fdx$$

Which is the Work Energy Theorem in a nutshell.